# Fade in img's onLoad - Caroufredsel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, caroufredsel

I am using the Caroufredsel plug-in for a gallery I have and would like to have the images in the gallery fade in on page load.

Here is a link to the gallery: http://tamedia.ca/marlowe/collection-aw12.html

This is the script I have used to initiate the plug-in:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#thumbs").carouFredSel({
        synchronise: ['#images', false, true],
        width: "100%",
        height: 145,
        items: {
            width: 95,
            height: 145,
            visible: 19,
            start: -9
        },
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            pauseOnHover: true
        },
        auto: 5000,
        debug: true,
        prev: {
            button: "#prev-thumbs",
            key: "left"
        },
        next: {
            button: "#next-thumbs",
            key: "right"
        }
    });

    $('#images').carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: 1,
        scroll: {
            fx: 'fade'
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the onCreate() function of Caroufredsel for this purpose.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how the script would look? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#thumbs").carouFredSel({
        onCreate: function {
        /* PUT YOUR ONLOAD CODE HERE */
        }
        synchronise: ['#images', false, true],
        width: "100%",
        height: 145,
        items: {
            width: 95,
            height: 145,
            visible: 19,
            start: -9
        },
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            pauseOnHover: true
        },
        auto: 5000,
        debug: true,
        prev: {
            button: "#prev-thumbs",
            key: "left"
        },
        next: {
            button: "#next-thumbs",
            key: "right"
        }
    });

    $('#images').carouFredSel({
        auto: false,
        items: 1,
        scroll: {
            fx: 'fade'
        }
    });
});
```